# Why setDecorations add +1 to the ranges?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to decorate some ranges in a file and `setDecorations` function:

```
window.showTextDocument(url, {preview: false, viewColumn: ViewColumn.One}).then(function (editor) {
    editor.setDecorations(decoration, ranges);
});
```

`ranges` is an array of `Range` that its first range starts in (line:200, char: 0) and end in (line: 205 char: 5), for some reason the decoration actually apply to line 201 till line 206.

I looked in the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/api/node/extHostTextEditor.ts#L451) and see that `setDecorations` function add to all ranges +1 for some reason.

Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ranges are 0 based lines and for some reason the text editir working with 1 base lines